# how to select multiple values using select2 widget in yii2

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

I am using select to widget in my project and 'multiple' => true

```
 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'task')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => $companiesList,
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select company type ...',],
                        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true,'multiple' => true,],
                    ]);?>
```

but when I select multiple values it gives error
[image]

how to select multiple values using select2??

Comment: Can you please add your model code?

Answer (score 0):

in your model change your rules add line :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
....
    ['task','safe']
....
               ] 
    }
```

and remove the task from 'string' line  rules!
in next step you have to store this ids in a many-to-many table or store that link string-delimter in single column  .

add this in your controller :

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

....
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))  { 
....
$task_string = "";
foreach($model->task as $singl_task){
  $task_string.= $singl_task."-";
}
$model->task = $task_string;
```

Comment: I want selected values to be string, how to do that

Comment: @kiamoz, why not use `implode(','yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($model->task))` and get rid of that `foreach` ;)

Comment: @Goli you can use implode , but my code let you add more flexibility and do  more with all tasks.. such add some  calculation on each task ...

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam chekc above